# PostgreSQL: How duplicate schema structure?

Tags: postgresql

My goal is to create a `temporary` schema, fill it from big data then drop my `public` schema and rename the `temporary` schema to `public`, in order to reduce the time the database is unavailable.

How to duplicate schema structure into `temporary` schema?

Comment: Why do you want to do this. This sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: @NickBailey You mean, there's a better solution to solve my problem ? If yes, what would you recommend ?

Comment: To solve your problem, we first have to know what your problem is. And why should a database be unavailable when you add new data to it?

Comment: Right, the question is 'why do you need to duplicate your schema and then drop it'. What goal do you have that couldn't be accomplished by an in place edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never dropped public schema, but:

```
pg_dump --schema-only --schema=public | set '%s/public\./temporary\./g' | psql -h samehost
DROP  SCHEMA public;
ALTER SCHEMA temporary RENAME TO public;
```

Comment: and how do you duplicate the `public` schema structure to `temporary` ?

Comment: oh! I didn't read that part: try pg_dump --schema-only --schema=public | set '%s/public\./temporary\./g' | psql -h samehost